# How to set maximum and minimum value color of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to set the color of maximum and minimum in highcharts. Unfortunately, I'm unable to do it. I've searched a lot but unable to get the answer. From data, I'll know maximum and minimum value of each row & I want to set the color for minimum and maximum values of each row using highcharts.

This is my current output:

[image]

but I want this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
    options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
    defaultOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
            width: 120,
            height: 20,
            style: {
                overflow: 'visible'
            },

            // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
            skipClone: true
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            tickPositions: [0]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            hideDelay: 0,
            outside: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false,
                lineWidth: 1,
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                fillOpacity: 0.25
            },
            column: {
                negativeColor: '#910000',
                borderColor: 'silver'
            }
        }
    };

options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

return hasRenderToArg ?
    new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
    new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
};
```

Comment: This may not completely answer your question but will lead you to the solution. Please check this codepen: https://codepen.io/prinkpan/pen/aMjqrw the main bit in it is setting `data` in the `doChunk()` method

Comment: If you know the maximum and minimum values the solution should be easy. Have you tried to add `series.column.data.color` property to these particular points?

Comment: @Wojciech Chmiel No I haven't tried.But how to calculate min and max?

Comment: You should have min and max from your data, isn't it?

Comment: Yes I have .but Can't understand how to calculate min and max in do chunk()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the minimum and maximum number from data and than color.

Paste the following code in do chunk function.

```
                a = Math.max(...data);
                b = Math.min(...data);
                for(j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if (data[j] == a) {
                        data[j] = { y: parseInt(a), color: '#A9D08E' };
                    }
                    if (data[j] == b) {
                        data[j] = { y: parseInt(b), color: '#F4B084' };
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use colorAxis property, you can define minColor and maxColor in ColorAxis. See example here     `https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/coloraxis/mincolor-maxcolor/`

```
colorAxis: {
        min: 1,
        max: 1000,
        type: 'logarithmic',
        minColor: '#efecf3',
        maxColor: '#990041'
    },
```

Comment: In my case, min and max is not static . How this will help ?